# Autoscroll RichTextArea in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a Created a logwindow in my project in C#

[image]

This log window is nothing but a `richtexbox`. I am appending the lines in RichTextbox whenever a method is called.

What i want is  : It should `autoscroll` down whenever a new line is Appended in  the rich text box.

Can anybody tell me how to do it.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rich Text box scroll to the bottom when new data is written to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416608/rich-text-box-scroll-to-the-bottom-when-new-data-is-written-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just have to set the "cursor" to the end of the box by setting the `SelectionStart` and afterwards tell the control to scroll to the caret (= the selection):

```
rtfBox.SelectionStart = rtfBox.Text.Length;
rtfBox.ScrollToCaret();
```